# Sensible approach for animated heartbeat/oscilloscope effect in WPF/xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, animation

I'd like to have an animated heartbeat/oscilloscope effect for my application, similar to the following:

[image]

I'm not sure what approach to take, though. Approaches I've considered (but don't know where to begin with) are:

- Having the whole line prepared as a path, but then covering it up with an opaque rectangle that has a window in it so you can see the line through it.
- Having the path prepared, and drawing the line along it, moving it along a bit at a time.

Note this is an effect rather than an actual data-bound oscilloscope (which I'm expecting would be much harder).

Comment: Would you like it to be realistic? Because those representative complexes are kinda ridiculous :D [PhysioBank](http://www.physionet.org/physiobank/) has a large number of free ECGs in digital form. You could save the point data and redraw the points as a path at 25mm/s (usual ECG rate). I have an ECG viewer using the PhysioBank API in WPF that does just that and works pretty well on a relatively new machine.

Answer (score 6):

I realize it has been almost 3 years, but thought I would pass on what I found... http://www.yazgelistir.com/makale/silverlight-ile-bir-ekg-animasyonu

Just in case the page goes away...

```
<Canvas
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Width="300" Height="200"
  Background="#FF000000"
  x:Name="Page"
  >
  <Canvas.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" x:Name="Storyboard1">
          <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Layer_1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Clip).(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.StartPoint)">
            <SplinePointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-31.5,-28.5"/>
            <SplinePointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="308,-29.5"/>
          </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Layer_1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Clip).(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.Segments)[0].(LineSegment.Point)">
            <SplinePointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-9.5,-28.5"/>
            <SplinePointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="330,-29.5"/>
          </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Layer_1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Clip).(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.Segments)[1].(LineSegment.Point)">
            <SplinePointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-9.5,228.5"/>
            <SplinePointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="330,227.5"/>
          </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          <PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Layer_1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Clip).(PathGeometry.Figures)[0].(PathFigure.Segments)[2].(LineSegment.Point)">
            <SplinePointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-31.5,228.5"/>
            <SplinePointKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="308,227.5"/>
          </PointAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Canvas.Triggers>
    <Canvas x:Name="Layer_1" Width="300" Height="200" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
      <Canvas.Clip>
        <PathGeometry>
          <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="-31.5,-28.5">
            <LineSegment Point="-9.5,-28.5"/>
            <LineSegment Point="-9.5,228.5"/>
            <LineSegment Point="-31.5,228.5"/>
          </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
      </Canvas.Clip>
    <Path Width="300.488" Height="194.519" Canvas.Left="-0.594986" Canvas.Top="5.19727" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF23FF00" Data="F1 M 0.405014,137.11L 30.6097,137.11L 42.6763,76.7877L 53.0284,146.736L 59.0672,127.484L 67.733,137.11L 153.962,137.11L 181.568,6.19727L 203.997,198.717L 223.839,65.2365L 241.092,151.87L 248.857,137.11L 298.893,137.11"/>
  </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this tutorial the functionality to plot the ECG graph is in place for winforms... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/GraphPlotting.aspx

Use the same thing against any WPF chart control... a free one is available in WPF toolkit... http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Create a path containing many segments, either line segments or bezier segment. Use as many segments as the scope is wide. Then move or animate the y coordinate of the segment's start and end points.

You could re-use the data to have a repeating effect or generate new values and shift those in from the left.

This way you do not generate more object than you need.